# rails net-ldap: uninitialized constant ::NET error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ldap, openldap

I have installed openLDAP and using net-ldap to work with that in Ruby on Rails. The thing here is i am able to bind and serach with this gem, but qhen it comes to add an entry to directory:

```
@auth = {:method => :simple, :username => "cn=admin,dc=example,dc=test", :password => "password"}
PORT = 389
HOST = "127.0.1.1"
NET::LDAP.open(:host => HOST, :port => PORT, :auth => @auth) do |ldap|
@ldap.add(:dn => dn, :attributes => attr) .
```

this error stop everyhing: `uninitialized constant LdapsController::NET`,[point to open line]

- net-ldap is installed
- ruby 2
- rails 4
- os: Ubuntu 13.4

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
Net::LDAP
```

Case matter!